# Regex/Notepad++ to strip everything but links from an HTML page?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a long page of HTML code.  Sprinkled in the code is a variety of links in the form of

```
 <a href="/whatever.com">Whatever</a>
```

What regex do I need for Search|Replace in Notepad++ to strip out the entire page of HTML and just leave an isolated listing of the links like this:

```
 whatever.com
 whichever.com
 whoever.com
```

Comment: There is the problem with liquification of the n​erves of the sentient... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/122139

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

Find:

```
^[^"]+.([^"]+).*
```

Replace:

```
$1
```

To filter the title,

Find:

```
</?[^>]*.
```

Replace:

```
empty string
```